# Is "The hotel which I stayed" grammatical wrong?

Tags: sentence-construction

So like the title says, personally I think use "which" to emphasize which specific hotel I stayed, however it seems people would use "where" instead, as "The hotel where I stayed", so is the title wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *stay* has a transitive sense, but the use here is intransitive. That means you can't *stay a hotel*, with *hotel* as direct object.
There are two options for the sense you want:
*the hotel where I stayed*
or
*the hotel [which] I stayed at*
(here *which* is optional)

[Merriam-Webster *stay*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stay)
intransitive verb
5  to take up residence : lodge

Comment: or 'the hotel in/at which I stayed"